# What does slash / do in selector name in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is the code, can someone explain how it works.

```
.top-2\.5{
   top:0.625rem;
}
.top-1\/2{
   top:50%;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but I would guess it escapes the next character so that it is part of the class name.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is used as an escape sequence.  Refer [this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#:%7E:text=CSS%20represents%20escaped%20characters%20in,that%20is%20all%20you%20need.) to know more.

Those `CSS` class name can be referenced in `HTML` tags as follows:

```
<body>
  <h1 class = "top-1/2">My First Heading</h1>
  <p class = "top-2.5">My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

Full code reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .top-2\.5{
     top:0.625rem;
     color: red;
  }
  .top-1\/2{
     top:50%;
     color: blue;
  }
</style>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class = "top-1/2">My First Heading</h1>
  <p class = "top-2.5">My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```